# How to display a separating line in Highcharts exporting menu?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, export, line

There is a straight line below the "Print chart" entry of the exporting tool of Highcharts. I'd like to generate one or two more of these, in order to separate the image from the data formats, as well as before adding additional links.

How can I generate the line? I tried it with a DIV, but that doesn't seem to be the solution (too much tweaking & tricking), neither a `<hr>`. So what is the best option?

Thanks for any hints!

[image]

Comment: so u want download PNG , download JPEG , download PDF and the others to be separated by a line?

Comment: @Mohit: Yes. Same for between "Download XLS" and "Link to more..."

Comment: can u post the code for the menu only so i can tell u where to put it , u just need to put 1 line of css

Comment: The menu is generated through [this Highcharts library](http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js).

Answer (score 5):

Using the Highcharts API, when defining the menu you can just add the following code as an element in the `exporting.buttons.contextButton.menuItems` array:

```
{ separator: true }
```

The following code would be added directly inside your chart options and shows how to separate every single item ([see it on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gs7h843n/)):

```
exporting: {
    buttons: {
        contextButton: {
            menuItems: [{
                textKey: 'printChart',
                onclick: function () {
                    this.print();
                }
            }, {
                separator: true
            }, {
                textKey: 'downloadPNG',
                onclick: function () {
                    this.exportChart();
                }
            }, {
                separator: true
            }, {
                textKey: 'downloadJPEG',
                onclick: function () {
                    this.exportChart({
                        type: 'image/jpeg'
                    });
                }
            }, {
                separator: true
            }, {
                textKey: 'downloadPDF',
                onclick: function () {
                    this.exportChart({
                        type: 'application/pdf'
                    });
                }
            }, {
                separator: true
            }, {
                textKey: 'downloadSVG',
                onclick: function () {
                    this.exportChart({
                        type: 'image/svg+xml'
                    });
                }
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Yes, I had seen this before too. But because I am offering the download in CSV and XLS format too (via the external script [here](http://highslide-software.github.io/export-csv/export-csv.js)), hardcoding the above options hampers the display of CSV/XLS. Ok, I succeeded in manually adding the CSV export ([here the updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/luftikus143/gs7h843n/2/)), but not the XLS export. Any idea how this could be done?

Comment: Having some issues testing the code. Does this do anything? [JSFiddle with CSV and XLS](http://jsfiddle.net/gs7h843n/3/)